# Alternative to using the linux cp command without the -n flag available?

Tags: linux, cp

I'm making a script in bash that requires files to be copied. I tried using the `cp` command with the `-n` flag set but I found out that on some systems the `-n` flag is not available.

```
cp: invalid option -- n
```

I want this script to be portable enough so that users won't be required to update their `cp`.

What the `-n` flag does is copy only files from the source that are not already in the destination without prompting.

Is there an alternative to this?

Comment: I think this question would fit better on [unix.stackexchange.com](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I didn't know there was a stackexchange for unix. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the `-i` flag is available, `yes n | cp -i ...` should achieve the same as `cp -n ...`.

Answer (score 0):

Try `rsync -u`. Although is not exactly equivalent to `cp -n`, it may be what you actually want...

Comment: there is an rsync flag '--ignore-existing' (but I don't know how long it's been there)